# how to find the largest subsets of a correlation matrix whose correlation are below a given value?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I used following code to get a correlation matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,4))
df = df.corr()
```

say the df is as below

```
    0         1         2         3
0  1.000000 -0.156813  0.294344 -0.034569
1 -0.156813  1.000000 -0.238828  0.222677
2  0.294344 -0.238828  1.000000  0.071389
3 -0.034569  0.222677  0.071389  1.000000
```

the largest subsets of above correlation matrix whose correlation are below 0.23 is [0,1,3] and [1,2,3], as all correlations within [0,1,3] and [1,2,3] are below 0.23 and other subsets like [0,3], [1,2] only contains two elements.

if the df is 200 * 200 matrix, what's the quickest way to find such subsets? check all 2^200 possibilities would be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to create a graph and find its cliques.

You can achieve this with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org)'s [`find_clique`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html) after converting [`from_pandas_adjacency`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_adjacency.html):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df.lt(0.23))

cliques = list(nx.find_cliques(G))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 0], [1, 3, 2]]
```

Your graph:

[image]

Comment: this is indeed what I need, thanks. did some search ,the time complexity of find cliques is around O(1.4422^n) . so for a correlation matrix of 100 * 100, it would still be too slow to get an result. but I guess there is no better way.

Comment: Keep in mind that the matrix is 100x100 but you might have much less edges/nodes. If you're looking for cliques of a particular size you can also pre-filter the nodes with at least N neighbors.